# Load excel files within python based on date modified

Tags: python, excel

I am tring to load the last 30 days of excel files into python so I can check work isn't duplicated. The location has 1000's of old excel files (archived). I only want to look at the last 30 days of files.

My current code adds them alltogether:

```
for f in files_xlsx:
    os.chdir("path")
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Deal') 
    df = df.append(data)
```

I have been trying to use this:

```
os.chdir("path")
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(search_dir))
files = [os.path.join(search_dir, f) for f in files] 
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
```

However I am struggling with selecting those within the timeframe.

Any help very much welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem you're having is selecting only the files that are younger than 30 days, you can filter them for example like this:

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now()
def file_age(file):
    return now - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file))
relevant_files = [file for file in files 
                  if file_age(file) < datetime.timedelta(days=30)]
```